# android & facebook stream.publish problem... help!

Tags: android, facebook, stream, publish

HI all,

Im having a strange thing. Im having a code that was working that doesnt anymore. To me, I think i didnt make any changes...Can someone give me an idea what is wrong ??
I'm trying to publish a text with an image and a link using the attachment method of stream.publish.

here is the code :

```
            Bundle myParams = new Bundle();
            myParams.putString("message", "Je publie un TEST.");

            String attachment="{\"name\":\"Gran Turismo 5\",\"href\":\"http://www.unknown.com/?lang=fr\",\"caption\":\"Sony Computer Entertainment\",\"description\":\"Une vidéo proposée par Cedemo.\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://www.unknown.com/prepicture//thumb_title/15/15061_1.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://www.unknown.com/?lang=fr\"}],\"properties\":{\"Autre lien\":{\"text\":\"Cedemo\",\"href\":\"http://www.unknown.com\"}}}";

            myParams.putString("attachment",attachment);
            mFacebook.dialog(Example.this,"stream.publish",myParams, new PostSampleDialogListener());
```

What is happening is that I am getting only the "Message" text published on facebook and nothing about my attachment... There is no error code returned by the function. I dont understand, this code has been working before...

### THE SOLUTION

You have to You have to use the function URLEncoder.encode to encode your parameters.
Example :
myParams.putString("attachment", URLEncoder.encode("{\"name\":\""..... ))

Answer (score 0):

The attachment variable need to be URL Encoded !!